# bypass ssl check for one domain

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssl

Is there any way to byepass the ssl checking for one domain from my server?

The problem is when calling the url in the application. I need to call a url say `https://blog.domain.com:8444/application/current` or `https://xx.xx.xx.xx:8444/application/current`

Is there a way where I can bye-pass the ssl check for this particular domain from my application server? I have followed a tutorial

> http://turboflash.wordpress.com/2009/06/23/curl-adding-installing-trusting-new-self-signed-certificate/   However curl command still says 'SSL certificate problem'

What I Need is that my server will trust the two uls permanently and will show up them without checking the ssl validity.

Comment: Exactly what are you doing? What is the distribution?

Comment: I used curl  to call url specified above. curl says "SSL certificate problem". So followed http://turboflash.wordpress.com/2009/06/23/curl-adding-installing-trusting-new-self-signed-certificate/  still same issue. I use ubuntu 12.04 on both servers

Answer (score 3):

I gather you are  using CURL for something.  If you are using it from the command line, you basically have two choices:

- Specify the `-k` option (`--insecure`) to allow CURL to proceed in the event of an SSL verification failure.  This opens you to MitM attacks, but literally does not check the certificate's validity.
- Add the self-signed certificates to your trust root

If you only access SSL sites with self-signed certificates like this using your CURL command you can create a PEM file containing all the self-signed certificates.  Then, you can use the `--cacert` option to specify that file, and your validation should succeed only for those self-signed certificates (and importantly, not for "real" ones).

You could also add the self-signed certificates to the CA file CURL is currently using, which is typically curl-ca-bundle.crt located someplace dependent on your installation.

If you are not using it from the command line there should be parameters you can pass which are equivalent to this.

Comment: on using curl -k, the page is loading. But I need this https url to be trusted server wide. It should load this https url from browser or application or from command mode without  validating ssl.

Comment: Great.  I gave you a solution to that already - trust the self-signed SSL certificates, which act as their own CA certificates.  If you want to do that for a browser too you might have to add them to multiple trust roots, depending on your platform and software (I'll leave this as an exercise to you).  If you have a lot of them, establish enterprise PKI instead.

Comment: Falcon, I fixed it by adding the intermediate CA certificate to my servers /usr/share/ca-certificates directory and added the certificate name to /etc/ca-certificates.conf and then updated it with 'update-ca-certificates --fresh'. Once this is done the https url is accessible from server via browser or application or from command mode. Thanks